# Is it possible to bind a port with HTTPS in nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, docker, node.js, cloudflare

I have a graphql api that works when accessed with http://example.com:4001/graphql but does not work with https://example.com:4001/graphql which is obvious as https takes the port 443 and here I am saying to connect on port 4001 with https.

My traffic is passing through cloudflare where SSL is flexible, meaning any URL from browser till cloudflare is HTTPS and beyond that it does not matter till the source server.

On server, I have configured nginx, where port 4001 is used and on the location block /graphql I have the local graphql API running on the server. It can be seen below

```
    server {
            listen 4001; //Nginx port occupied on server
            server_name example.com;
    
            location /graphql {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:4007; //This is the local qraphql api
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            }
    
    }
```

Please note, there is no way I can change the URL from http://example.com:4001/graphql to  http://example.com/graphql [For some obvious reason] WHICH is quite straight forward to put a location /graphql block under port 443 or port 80 server blocks in NGINX and will work.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: HTTPS doesn't have to be 443; HTTPS _defaults_ to 443 while HTTP defaults to 80, but either of them can work on any port. However with many programs you cannot run BOTH on the SAME port; I think (recent) nginx can with some preread hackery. With CloudFlare Flexible the client can use HTTPS to CF while CF uses HTTP to your origin server -- and it DOES matter that it does so. This doesn't sound much like a professional environment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the required parameters...eg.

```
  listen 4001 ssl;
  --snip--
  ssl_certificate ssl.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key ssl.key;
```

then the listener will accept https

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).